# How to exclude negative values from plot of PGFPlots package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm plotting bar plot using this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows,calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\tikzset{
%Define standard arrow tip
>=stealth'
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
font=\normalsize\rmfamily,
line width=1 pt,
tick style={line width=.6pt}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style={shade,top color=gray,bottom color=white},
    height=8cm,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    bar width=1.2cm,
    minor y tick num=4,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Count},
    symbolic x coords={5--10 years,10--15 years, 15--20 years,20--25 years,Over 25 years},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords, 
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        x tick label style={font=\normalsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center},
        ]    \addplot[fill=green!25!gray] coordinates {(5--10 years,32) (10--15 years,12) (15--20 years,3) (20--25 years,2) (Over 25 years,3)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to have y minimum equal to 0. I have set:

```
...
ymin=0,
...
```

But as you can see, it does not work.

Please help to solve this problem.

And secondly. How to put values inside of the bar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove the `enlargelimits=0.15` if you don't want to enlarge the limits of the axis past the specified `ymin` value. To put the nodes inside the bars, use `every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north}`.

Comment: Thank you! It works. But why enlargelimits=0.15 make such effect?

Comment: @saldenisov: Because that's what `enlargelimits` is designed to do. From the [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/pgfplots.pdf): "Axis limits can be increased automatically using the `enlargelimits` option."

Comment: But if I need to use enlargelimits t effect x axis? What than should I do?Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pgfplots, by default, uses `enlargelimits=0.15` in all directions.
You can change this to `enlarge x limits=0.15` to only enlarge the limits in x direction, which then looks like this:

[image: enlarge x limits=0.15]

where `nodes near coords` manages to expand the y axis enough to include the nodes, but `enlarge x limits=0.15,enlarge y limits={value=0.15,upper}`, gives the more equally spaced lower picture.

[image: enlarge x limits=0.15,enlarge y limits={value=0.15,upper}]